# Xamarin.Forms Listview binding larger date and UI pause

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

1. `List<T>` has more than 300 elements
2. `Listview` binding this `List<T>` when page show, but delay is more than 10s

Code:

```
List<app_process> saveList = new List<app_process>();

public ProcessPage() {
  InitializeComponent();

  saveList = getProcessDatas();

  this.processList.ItemsSource = saveList;
}
```

I try to use Thread and dialog to optimize this problem but it is a failure.

```
List<app_process> saveList = new List<app_process>();
    public ProcessPage(){
       InitializeComponent();
      
        UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading");
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                saveList = getProcessDatas();
                this.processList.ItemsSource = saveList;
 
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                 UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                 });
            })).Start();
      
    }
```

What's wrong with it? How can I solve it?

Comment: First, determine how much of the time is taken by `getProcessDatas`. Is that taking most of the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try overriding OnAppearing method and then run your processor async.

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
   UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading");

   var data = await Task.Run(() => getProcessDatas());

   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
   {
       this.processList.ItemsSource = data;
       UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
   });
 }
```

Comment: You `await` the result of `Task.Run`. That prevents page from appearing until the data is loaded. For this purpose, correct code is to NOT await. And move code inside Task.Run: `Task.Run(() => { var data = getProcessDatas(); Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( ... ); }`  While this change still won't solve the original question of reducing the total time, it will allow "Loading" to appear while the time passes.

Comment: good! this is right!THX